# Django : Fetch API redirects to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, django, fetch

Im trying to send data to my django backend using javascript Fetch API.
My current working url is `127.0.0.1:8000/store`

And im trying to send data to `127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product/` using fetch as follows
urls.py

```
path('recommend_product/',product_utils.recommend_product,name = "recommend_product"),
```

```
 var url = '/recommend_product/'
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 'productId': productId })
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json()
                })

                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('data:', data)
                    location.reload()
                })
        } else {
            alert('Please Login to recommend products')
        }
```

My problem is that Fetch API redirecting me to  `'127.0.0.1:8000/store/recommend_product/'` instead of `127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product/`.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Although i dont think this is the best way, try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's something to do with [how Django processes requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request).

Your url is only defined as `var url = '/recommend_product/'`, so it may be going to `'127.0.0.1:8000/store/recommend_product/'` by default if `/store` is your first defined url path.

Edit: To correct it, be more specific with your url

`var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product/'`

Comment: Fully write out the url var url = '127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product/

Comment: i tried it mylself before and im getting ```NotFound /store/127.0.0.1:8000/recommend_product/```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on my projects.
Your best bet might be to use javascript, as in `${window.location.host}/your_endpoint/`.
This would make it quite dynamic.